# python counting pairs from two separate lists without unique values in the list (I don't think sets will work)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer to this.
I want to count the pairs in two separate lists.  Each pair is counted including duplicates (this is why I believe sets wont work) For example:

```
fun(A, B):
   return count

if A = [1 1 0 0] and B = [1 2 2 1]
returns 2 and not 1
if A = [1 1 0 0] and B = [1 3 3 3]
returns 1
if A = [1 2 2 0] and B = [1 3 2 2]
returns 3
```

specifically I have made a mastermind type game and this is to count the right color wrong spot total (after right color right spot are removed from the lists)

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't seem very pythonic.

```
def count_func(A,B)       
    count = 0
       for b in reversed(B):
           used = False
           for a in reversed(A):
               if b == a and not used:
                        A.remove(b) #remove that from list
                        B.remove(b)
                        count += 1
                        used = True
    return count
```

I am using Python 3 by the way.  Thanks for the help and if this has been answered before let me know.

EDIT:
Corrected second example and tried to clarify

Comment: what's the logic behind the pairs in 2 lists? it's really not clear

Comment: Should this return 1 and not 0? if A = [1 1 0 0] and B = [3 3 3 3],  returns 1

Comment: The idea is to count all the pairs of `(x,y)`, such that `x in A`, `y in B` and `x==y`.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove both the boolean 'used' and the reversing of the strings:

```
def count_func(A,B):
    count = 0
    for b in B:
        for a in A:
            if b == a:
             A.remove(a)
             count += 1
             break
return count
```

Comment: This is correct, but not optimal. It will give you O(N**2) complexity, so it will work slowly for big lists.

Comment: Isn't the reverse necessary to keep the indexing proper in the for loop? The boolean is just because i have trouble breaking a for loop, but unnecessary.

Comment: No because in each iteration of 'for b in B', array A is reread upon the call on 'for a in A'.

Comment: Example:

    for b in B: #[1, 2, 3] b = 1
        for a in A: #[2, 1, 3] a = 2
            if b == a: #1 != 2

    for b in B: #[1, 2, 3] b = 1
        for a in A: #[2, 1, 3] a = 1
            if b == a: # 1 == 1
                A.remove(a) #remove 1, A = [2, 3]
                break #no longer in 'for a in A loop but still within for b in B loop

    for b in B: #[1, 2, 3] b = 2
        for a in A: #A now gets assessed as A = [2, 3] and a = 2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get the size of the overlap between A and B including repeated entries?

If I understand this correctly you can use Python's `Counter` from the `collections` module. A `Counter` takes a list and creates a mapping from each entry in the list to how often it appears.

```
from collections import Counter

def func(A, B):
    a = Counter(A)
    b = Counter(B)
    count = 0
    for key in a:
        count += min(a[key], b[key])

    return count
```

This runs in `O(n)` time where `n = max(len(A), len(B))`

Comment: thanks what do you mean by [key]  i get an error about key being undefined does it stand for something?

Comment: Apologies I meant to use key in the for loop :)

Comment: Very nice! But you are mistaken: the correct answer to the second case is 1, and your own code also says so :)

Comment: Whoops didn't see the 1 in the second list! Sounds good hope this helped.

Comment: That was an edit.  Thanks though this does work.

Answer (score 1):

A quicker implementation in Python would be:

```
def count_pairs(A, B):
    a, b = sorted(A), sorted(B)
    i = j = 0
    count = 0
    while i<len(a) and j<len(b):
        if a[i]==b[j]:
            count += 1
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif a[i]<b[j]:
            i += 1
        else:   # a[i]>b[j]
            j += 1
    return count
```

Through sorting the lists this achieves O(N*log N) algorithm complexity, instead of O(N**2) (assuming the lists are of the same length).

Also, it will work in Python 3 as well as in Python 2.